# Reduce re-rendering time in Angular

Tags: angular, angular10

I have an angular application and one page in the application is 'Role Config'. The page contains more than 200 controls (mat-select, mat-multiselect etc). And the whole data is being received from a single API. The data received from API is around the size of 9 MB and after receiving the data from API, I need to set the data to the controls.

Now the problem is, after the data is appended to the controls, the screen is stuck for sometimes. I guess the issue is the page is re-rendering on updating each controls and hence the page gets stuck. I see the page is stuck for around 30 seconds after the API is completed. I need to avoid this situation. Can someone suggest how I can do it?

Thanks in advance

```js
const controlListData1: any = [];
const controlListData2: any = [];
.;
.;
const controlListData200: any = [];

this.getData().then(data => {
  this.controlListData1 = data.controlList1data.map(item => 
    return {
      Id: item.ID,
      Text: item.TEXT
    })
    
  this.controlListData2 = data.controlList2data.map(item => 
    return {
      Id: item.ID,
      Text: item.TEXT
    })
    
    etc;
    .;
    .;
  this.controlListData200 = data.controlList200data.map(item => 
    return {
      Id: item.ID,
      Text: item.TEXT
    })
})
```

Comment: You'd need to provide way more context than that! Rendering time is one thing, but you could time the maps execution also... Without having more details on your component it will be hard to optimize. 30 seconds is a LOT though.

Comment: What you could always do is switch ChangeDetection to `OnPush` and work with subjects and the async pipe. This way you could split the data up into different parts and render them one at a time by updating the subjects in the view one by one.
For more info, have a look at this link: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-reactive-templates/

If you can provide a bit more info, e.g. how your template looks, we could give you a more specfic suggestion.

Comment: What more of an information do you require? @Salketer Think of a component with n number of variables each used to store the data of n different controls. Currently am updating them one by one. So the rendering takes a lot of time. Instead is there any way I can update the components all at one's or render the UI only once ?

Comment: THe problem is that we do not see your controller... Are there any functions used by the template? What exactly do you mean by update the controls one by one? You're not showing anything like that so it is very hard to help and point in a direction.